# Understanding WAIT_TIME_MS

Tags: sql-server

**Test scenario**:
I am only one user on database. I reset `sys.dm_os_wait_stats`. I run a `SELECT` query (table scan).

**Result**:
Execution time = 20 minutes, but `sys.dm_os_wait_stats -> PAGEIOLATCH_SH -> Wait_time_ms` = 40 minutes (2 580 252)

**Question**:
How is it possible that in 20 minutes: `wait_time_ms > execution time` ?

Comment: Your query could run in parallel, with two threads accumulating twice the wait time

Comment: That is also cumulative wait time across the instance, not just a particular database.

Answer (score 4):

As the two comments mention, there are two things at work here.

1. `sys.dm_os_wait_stats` records accumulated wait times since the server was restarted. So if the server has been up for a while, these can be fairly high. To get a meaningful value out of `sys.dm_os_wait_stats`, you need to take two snapshots e.g. 5 minutes apart and compare them to each other. Keep in mind, there you cannot tie them to a single connection. Anything on the server that is waiting for something during that time will cause a change in one of the values returned by `sys.dm_os_wait_stats`.
2. If a query gets executed in parallel, each thread will use up CPU time as well as potentially wait time. So both the total CPU time as well as the total wait time for a single query can be higher than the elapsed time.